# What does vorticity and circulation physically signify?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, vortex

When I see say a circulation value of 0, pi, 2pi or -12pi, what should this mean to me?

I am a beginner in fm and have been trying to understand vorticity and circulation's physical significance and what do they actually represent.

To give it a bit of context -

I understand Vorticity as the local rotation of a fluid particle about it's own axis. So when you have vorticity of say 2k-hat, it means that the given velocity vector field has the tendency to rotate the fluid particle at a particular location about its own axis where vorticity vector is directed along z axis and this 2 is just a number which doesnot have any significance of itself but shows relative strength of rotation.

In a similar manner what does circulation signify? Also is my understanding of vorticity correct?

Comment: Questions on this site should be formatted such that there is a single well-defined question being asked.